# How to have a unique error message for two textfields

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Hi I have a little problem since a few days... I'm trying to find out how to make two fields display an error message at the same place.

I tried with a Formfield but it bugs me because the second textformfield falls in error since I have only one state. I also tried with a simple Formfield but I can't set my validator message in a variable and then display it in a padding.

Would you have an idea please?

Thanks in advance.

Example : I would like to display my error message instead of the Text widget "Error message".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve your problem.

Take a look at this screenshot and code:

Screenshot - [image: Screenshot]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _errorText = '';

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _key,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 50,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              _errorText = 'Please enter some text';
                            });
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 50,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              _errorText = 'Please enter some text';
                            });
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(_errorText),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {}
                },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! I have another constraint, I'am already in a form. And therefore it does not validate. I have tried with a formfield state but the second field is an error when I start to write in the first one because it has the same state. Is there a way to get around this ? Thanks.